# React & TypeScript, getting errors when adding conditionally onClick prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to conditionally add an `onClick` function to my TypeScript React component like so:

```js
<div onClick={(!disabled && onClick) ?? undefined}>{children}</div>
```

But I get this error:

```
Type 'false | (() => void) | undefined' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement> | undefined'.
  Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement>'.
```

My onClick prop variable is of type `onClick?: () => void;` in my props interface. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `onClick` is typed, an easy way to avoid those type errors is to do as below. Notice I'm not passing `onClick` directly, as type `() => void` wouldn't be assignable to the click handler.

```js
{!disabled && onClick ? (
  <div onClick={(e) => onClick()}>{children}</div>
) : (
  <div>{children}</div>
)}
```